# Hiding two columns of GridView while printing it Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
 function printform() {
        var printContent = document.getElementById("<%= PrintPanelID.ClientID %>");

        var windowUrl = "about:blank";
        var uniqueName = new Date();
        var windowName = "Print" + uniqueName.getTime();
        var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, "left=50000,top=50000,width=0,height=0");
        printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.focus();
        printWindow.print();
        printWindow.close();
    }

    function HidColumn() {

        // col_num = document.getElementById("Button").value;
        rows = document.getElementById("<%= GV1.ClientID %>").rows;
        for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            rows[i].cells[8].style.display = "none";
        }

        for (j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
            rows[j].cells[9].style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    // change logic to suit taste
    function clicked() {
        var b = HidColumn();
        if (b)
            printform()
        return b;
    }


  <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageAlign="Right" ImageUrl="images/printer.jpg"
                    Style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 15px" OnClick="ImageButton2_Click" Width="36px"
                    OnClientClick="return clicked()" Visible="false" />
```

**However nothing is happening when i click the ImageButton**

Comment: I agree with the steve answer and you should modify your function HidColumn() to return either true or false ..

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't make sense:   `var b = HidColumn();`

The function HidColumn doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

AS I said that I agree with the steve answer and you should modify your function HidColumn to return either true or false.
One more point i would like to mention that if you return false from clicked() Then `postback` will not happen otherwise it will call `ImageButton2_Click` event on server.

```
function HidColumn() {

        // col_num = document.getElementById("Button").value;
        rows = document.getElementById("<%= GV1.ClientID %>").rows;
        for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            rows[i].cells[8].style.display = "none";
        }

        for (j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
            rows[j].cells[9].style.display = "none";
        }
        if(someCondition)return true;
         else return false;
    }
```

**UPDATE:-**
you have set the control visibility to False , hence the control will not be rendered.
Hence you cannot get the Element in javascript because there will be no HTML for that control.
if you want hide the control just use Javascript :-

```
<asp:somecontrol id="ctrl" style="display:none" />
```

Answer (score 0):

simply put your hide column code in a print function like this:

```
function PrintPage() {

        rows = document.getElementById("<%= Gv1.ClientID %>").rows;
        for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            rows[i].cells[8].style.display = "none";
            rows[i].cells[9].style.display = "none";
        }
        var printContent = document.getElementById('<%= pnlDtls.ClientID %>');
        var printWindow = window.open("All Records", "Print Panel", 'left=50000,top=50000,width=0,height=0');
        printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.focus();
        printWindow.print();
    }
```